# Acceder a varios input con Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo este código para agregar una clase `hidden` a un párrafo

Pero tengo 3 input's y hacer lo mismo para cada `input` es un poco incomodo, intenté hacerlo con `each`, pero no tuve éxito.

Los Inputs son los siguientes:

```js
$("#lastname").on('input', function() {
    if((($(this).val().length)) > 0) {
        $('#error-nombre').addClass('hidden');
    }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="text"class="form-control" id="lastname" name="lastname">
    <p class="error-title hidden" id="error-lastname"></p>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="text"class="form-control" id="name" name="name">
    <p class="error-title hidden" id="error-name"></p>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="text"class="form-control" id="age" name="age">
    <p class="error-title hidden" id="error-age"></p>
</div>
```

Solo quiero tener una función que me detecte el `input` que estoy escribiendo y agregue la clase `hidden`

Comment: has utilizado el evento onFocus? con este puedes obtener la entrada del elemtno de un formulario

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para esto puede simplemente buscar al elemento hermano con la clase `error-title`, esto se logra con [siblings()](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/) para luego aplicar el `hide()` cuando la condición sea verdadera  y `show()` cuando no.

Además deberá eliminar la clase `hidden` en cada párrafo para que en principio se muestren todos y agregar la clase `entrada` con la cuál asignaremos el listener. *(Ejem, use show y hide , pero podría haber hecho también con addClass y removeClass)*

```js
$(".entrada").on('input', function() {
    if((($(this).val().length)) > 0) {
      $(this).siblings('.error-title').hide();
    }
    else{
      $(this).siblings('.error-title').show();
    }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control entrada" id="lastname" name="lastname">
    <p class="error-title" id="error-lastname">Lastname</p>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control entrada" id="name" name="name">
    <p class="error-title" id="error-name">Name</p>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control entrada" id="age" name="age">
    <p class="error-title" id="error-age">Age</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Para eso necesitarías ver cual de los **input** es el que cambia, y con `this`, aplicarías la propiedad a el en especifico, te quedaría así:

supongo que tengas los tres input dentro de algún **div** como contenedor

```
<div id="contenedor">

    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text"class="form-control" id="lastname" name="lastname">
        <p class="error-title hidden" id="error-lastname"></p>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text"class="form-control" id="name" name="name">
        <p class="error-title hidden" id="error-name"></p>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text"class="form-control" id="age" name="age">
        <p class="error-title hidden" id="error-age"></p>
    </div>

</div>
```

ahora con `jquery`, utilizarías lo mismo que tienes implementado , pero para los **input** del contenedor:

```
$("#contenedor input").on('input', function() {
    if((($(this).val().length)) > 0) {
        $('#error-nombre').addClass('hidden');
    }
});
```

de esta manera te serviría para cuando se escriba en cualquiera de los **input** del contenedor. Saludos

> Nota: Si agregas en futuro mas **input** dentro del contenedor, el código seguiría funcionando y no tendrías que agregar mas código

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar múltiples selector y utilizar closest()

```
$("#lastname, #name, #age").on('input', function() {
    if((($(this).val().length)) > 0) {
        $('#lastname').
        closest( ".error-handler" ).
        addClass('hidden');
    }
});
```

Pero a tu html tienes que agregar el erro handler como clase y repetirla

espero te ayude.